# Connect codeigniter database with SQL server on different server?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter

I recently created a web app and I want to upload it to my production server. But, I placed the App server and database server on two different servers. I created the web app using codeigniter and the database using SQL Server, and I got trouble to connect to the DB using my recent connection.

Here is my codeigniter's DB config:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '172.64.23.229, 1433',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'database' => 'AMAS_PROD',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I tried using the database server's IP but still it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your server which has the database should support remote DB connection. You've to configure the remote db connection to use your db outside your server.

Say, if you are using linux based server and mysql as db, you can follow this doc:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: okay, i already set up the TCP IP Connection on my DB server and it worked now, THANK YOU!